# POSXlt and filter() in R

Tags: r, date, posixlt

I would like to use POSIXlt for date/time column in my data.frame and the filter() function to filter it. My code is below.

I believe that I have properly converted the date data to numerical but still I get an error.

How can I sort it out without changing POSIXlt to POSIXct?

```
require(dplyr)
x <- "2017-03-30"
y <- "2017-04-04"

name <- c("a","b","c","d")
weight <- c(2,3,1,5)
t <- c("2017-03-27 08:13:17", "2017-03-30 01:05:01", "2017-04-03 02:43:35", "2017-05-27 23:13:03")
z <- data.frame(name, weight, t)
z$t <- as.POSIXlt(z$t, tz="GMT", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
str(z)
z$t

x <- unclass(as.Date(x)) # integer
str(x)
y <- unclass(as.Date(y)) # integer
str(y)

d <- filter(z, between(unclass(as.Date(t)), x, y))
```

The error this throws:

Error: Column `t` is a date/time and must be stored as POSIXct, not POSIXlt.

Comment: What's the downside of converting to `POSIXct`? Also, it seems that you are using `dplyr`. Always declare the package you are using (here for instance the issue is a requirement for `dplyr` date comparisons).

Comment: thanks @nicola, the above excerpt is part of a large code and I don't want to modify the rest. Thanks for the package reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dplyr` classes does not handle `POSIXlt` columns (which are `list` objects internally), while they can deal with `POSIXct` objects, which are just numbers.

If you intend to stick with `dplyr` you have to convert the `t` column:

```
z$t<-as.POSIXct(z$t)
#now this works
d <- filter(z, between(as.Date(t), x, y))
```

If you don't want to coerce the column, you can subset with standard base operators:

```
z[as.Date(z$t)>=x & as.Date(z$t)<=y,]
```